# How to get the shortest time and longest time(or timespan) from a list using LINQ?

Tags: linq-to-objects

I am trying to get the longest and shortest timespan in a list using LINQ.
My code looks something like this

List listofTimeSpans = new List();

adding the timespans to listofTimeSpans in a foreach loop.

Please help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create the list as

```
var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
```

then

```
var min = listofTimeSpans.Min();
var max = listofTimeSpans.Max();
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking at it and there is OrderBy and OrderByDescending functions. Do you know how to order the timespan with total seconds? 
Thank you for you reply in advance.

Comment: You could either use listofTimeSpans.Sort() or 
var ordered = listofTimeSpans.OrderBy(t=>t);
Both have the same results. I didn't understand what you mean by ordering with total seconds, but you can also use var ordered = listofTimeSpans.OrderBy(t=>t.Seconds);

Comment: I am new to LINQ and was thinking wrong. Max and Min functions worked for me.
Thank you again.